# Using Output Cache in MVC for Object Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, outputcache

This is my controller method. Can anyone explain how I could write outputcache for the following method on the server.

```
    public JsonResult GetCenterByStateCityName(string name, string state, string city, bool sportOnly, bool rvpOnly)
    {
        var result = GetCenterServiceClient().GetCentersByLocation(name, city, state, sportOnly, rvpOnly).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You want caching for a POST method ?

Comment: Yes , I want the caching for a POST Method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx

In a nutshell, just set the Attribute on your Action

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "SaveContactProfile", Duration = 10)]
public JsonResult SaveContact(Contact contact)
{
    var result = GetContactServiceClient().SaveContact(contact);
    return Json(result);
}
```

**-- UPDATE --**

If you're making a direct Ajax call via jQuery, the OutPutCache could be ignored based on the "cache" parameter - which is set to true by default.

For instance, your parameter would be ignored if you're doing something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: someUrlVar,
    cache: true, /* this is true by default */
    success : function(data) {

    }
});
```

Just something to look at as you can cache that call two ways.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out now. Should we set the VaryByParam attribute?

Comment: I updated the information to include some key details about also using Ajax to cache. As for your question, here is a great article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Answer (score 3):

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "name;state;city;sportOnly;rvpOnly")]
public JsonResult GetCenterByStateCityName(string name, string state, string city, bool sportOnly, bool rvpOnly)
{
        var result = GetCenterServiceClient().GetCentersByLocation(name, city, state, sportOnly, rvpOnly).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
        return Json(result);
}
```

The `Duration` value is 3600 seconds here. Sot the cache will be valid for 1 hour. You need to give the `VaryByParam` property values because you want different results for different parameters.

Comment: Does VaryByParam = "*" accomodate for the condition where if there is a change in name or state, it would not take from previously cached result right?